# video no carga correctamente dentro de un svg

Tags: google-chrome, svg, video, firefox, opera

Tengo un svg donde hay un video de fondo e imágenes y texto encima,
En teoría el svg carga de arriba abajo del código  pero en chrome y en opera esto funciona.

```
    ~<svg class="img-responsive" version="1.1" preserveAspectRatio="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0" y="0" width="500" height="300" viewBox="0 0 500 300">
<foreignObject  width="500" height="300">
    <video autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" class="a491" x="0" y="0" >
   <source src="https://animacionesweb.online/videos/Spaceship-33411g.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>
                </video>
 </foreignObject>
    <text x="40" y="30"
        font-family="Verdana" font-size="25"fill="blue">soy un texto,grafico y imagen encima d eun video
  </text>
    <circle cx=100 cy=100 r=50 fill="#ddd"></circle>
    <image  xlink:href="https://animacionesweb.online/imagenes/imagenesclientes/nave6.png"  width="133" height="64" x="0" y="0"></image>

</svg>    ~
```

Un ejemplo mas claro es aquí https://animacionesweb.online
[example](https://animacionesweb.online)
[example](https://animacionesweb.online) miralo en los diferentes exploradores alguien sabe alguna solución gracias
,

Comment: Quieres que se vea arriba del texto el video?

Comment: si quiero que el video se quede de fondo .Esto es una prueba pero en mi pagina web animacionesweb.online el fallo es peor donde tengo un video de fondo y otro encima sabes solucionarlo¿¿ – jose manuel mateos terren hace 10 minuto

Answer (score 0):

solucionado foreignObject permite css

~

```
foreignObject{
    position:absolute; z-index:-1;
     }
```

~
      así consigo que el vídeo este en el fondo del svg y se vea en chrome